# Cassandra and hector upgrade to 1.0 and unit testing

Tags: cassandra, hector

We have been using Cassandra 0.7 and since the stable version of cassandra 1.0.0 is out, we planned to upgrade to it. Its low risk since we are not in production yet. We were using hector 0.7-29 which had testutils package and a EmbeddedServerHelper class that we used to start a embedded server in all our unit tests.

However the upgraded version of hector 1.0-1 (which is for cassandra 1.0.x) has removed this package (me.prettyprint.cassandra.testutils) from its core distribution.

I would like to know the plan moving forward for unit testing using the new hector 1.0-1 api client. Is there a way to start cassandra embedded server any more?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new 'test' module which holds EmbeddedSchemaLoader and EmbeddedServerHelper. We took them out of core so they could be used outside of Hector (as the module now has no direct dependency on hector).

https://github.com/rantav/hector/tree/master/test

Let us know how everything works out.

Comment: After fixing some more things I ended with the below error. I have libthrift v 0.7.0 as a dependency which is the latest one. 16:33:29,531 ERROR AbstractCassandraDaemon:354 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.server.TServer.<init>(Lorg/apache/thrift/server/TServer$AbstractServerArgs;)

Comment: Cassandra and hector are both on thrift 0.6.1 - you are going to need to downgrade thrift most likely.

Comment: I had to include the libthrift 0/5/0 in group org.apache.cassandra.deps to get this passed. Since cassandra.yaml cannot have schema create statements, what is the best way to load the schema? I am thinking of replicating the code in EmbeddedSchemaLoader for our tests

Comment: removed libthrift 0.5.0 dependency as it works with 0.6.1. Thanks Nate

Comment: If you are really comfortable with maven, I would also suggest http://mojo.codehaus.org/cassandra-maven-plugin/ take a look at the CQL jdbc-driver for a good example of how to set this up: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/